# Sequelize authenticate using Managed Identity to Azure postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, sequelize.js, azure-managed-identity

Facing a connection error when trying to connect to Azure postgres instance using azure Managed identity. My app is developed on Typescript and I am using Sequelize as the ORM (sequelize npm v6.6.2). I am using the following config to establish connection to the database but this fails to authenticate.

```
config: Options = {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions : {
          authentication: {
              type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-vm',
              options: {
                  clientId: <AZURE_CLIENT_ID>,
              },
          },
    }
}
.
.
.
sequelize = new Sequelize(<DB_URL>, config)
```

I was able to successfully connect if I use password, by just replacing the dialectOptions with 'password'.

I have verified that I am able to connect to a Azure SQL Server instance using the below configuration without an issue.

```
config: Options = {
    database: <AZURE_SQL_DB>,
    host: <AZURE_SQL_SERVER>,
    dialect: 'mssql',
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      authentication: {
        type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-vm',
        options: {
          clientId: <AZURE_CLIENT_ID>,
        },
      },
    },
}
.
.
sequelize = new Sequelize(config)
```

NOTE: For this to work for MSSQL, I had to set the user-assigned managed identity as the 'Azure Active Directory Admin' in the server settings. So I have set it for the postgres instance as well.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, or is this capability not available yet on Azure Postgres instances?

Comment: Seems to be possible according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-connect-with-managed-identity

Comment: This functionality is available in Azure Database for PostgreSQL Single Server instances (Pg. version 10 & 11). For Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server instances ( pg. version 12 & 13) this option is not yet available. Which of these options are you using?

Comment: Using a single server postgres instance running version 11